# While Refering to the Account field why it will give error that variable dosenot exist please help

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

```
public class LeadHandler {
    public static void callme(List<Account>acc){
        for (Account a:acc){
            if(a.Type=='prospect'){//While refering Type it give an error
                                   that Varialble doesnot exist
                a.Rating='Hot';
                else {
                    a.Rating='Cold';
                }
            }  
   }     }
```

}

```
    }
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include the error message verbatim. It seems unlikely this code could generate the stated error message, as you have mismatched braces for your `if`/`else` blocks.

Comment: Your curly braces are unbalanced. This is likely to cause weird syntax and parsing errors.

Comment: @DavidReed You should have written an answer :D

Comment: Please include your code *verbatim*. The posted code could not throw the posted error.

Answer (score 1):

Your curly braces are unbalanced.

```
        if(a.Type=='prospect'){
            a.Rating='Hot';
            else {  // <---- missing close bracket before `else`
                a.Rating='Cold';
            }
```

This is likely to cause weird syntax and parsing errors, and the errors may not make sense. When your code is structurally broken, the parser sometimes is unable to understand elements that make sense to you.